# Why Selenium & PhantomJS cannot find tag, but Selenium & Chromedriver can find tag?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Why for this particular URL when using PhantomJS Selenium cannot find  tag, but when using Chromedriver Selenium can find it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('c:/Users/info_000/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs.exe')
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/Work/IdeaProjects/web_loaders/movie_scraper/chromedriver.exe')


url = 'https://gomovies.to/film/gilmore-girls-a-year-in-the-life-season-1-18045/'
print('opening %s' % url)
driver.get(url)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mvi-cover')
content.click()
print('after click')
src = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'video'))
).get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: Can you consider working on the Answers provided on your previous Questions by our SO volunteers, work on those and Accept/Close those discussions before raising a new Question? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, you are right. But I already did some research before asking this question. Most of answers on question "Selenium cannot find tag" are either use waits, or this tag is in <iframe>. These answers are not in such case

Answer (score 0):

I see the element with class 'thumb mvi-cover' not 'mvi-cover'.

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('thumb mvi-cover')
```

Comment: You are right. But it is not a root cause. This element has two CSS classes "thumb" and "mvi-cover". You can find by any of these classes. `content.click()` line is worked correct. But after that <video> tag cannot be found if PhantomJS is used

Comment: Try with sleep() or debug it and wait until driver loads all the content

Comment: thanks. But I already tried it. It doesn't help. It just found tag with Chromedriver and can't find this tag with PhantomJS

Comment: Try to set driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)  (can do this before driver.get())